# Can I find out what template is being used by a child page in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm displaying a list of child page using the code below. What i'm trying to achieve is to alter an icon depending on the template used by a child page in Wordpress.

Here's what I have so far :

```
<div class="col s12">
            <?php
            $args = array(
                'parent'        => $post->ID,
                'post_type'     => 'page',
                'post_status'   => 'publish',
                'sort_column'   => 'menu_order',
                'order'         => 'ASC'
            );
            $pages = get_pages($args);  ?>

            <ul class="collection" id="page-links">
                <?php foreach( $pages as $page ) { ?>
                <a href="<?php echo get_page_link( $page->ID ); ?>">
                    <li class="collection-item waves-effect waves-light" id="page-children"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?>
                        <span class="secondary-content">
                            <?php **IF TEMPLATE IS 'page-url.php'** : ?>
                                <i class="fa fa fa-external-link"></i>
                            <?php else :?>
                                <i class="fa fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </span>
                    </li>
                </a>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

I know I can determine the current template used by a page by using

```
<?php if(basename(get_page_template()) === 'page-url.php') : ?>
```

But I can't seem to find a way to find out the template for a child page (without being on the page itself).

Comment: You can use custom meta box for this requirement

Comment: Read: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55301/is-there-a-default-template-file-for-child-pages-subpages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `get_page_template_slug( $post_id )` and using your child page ID as `$post_id`.